# why am i getting this CastError in the Blog.update() function in the update route /blogs/:id (using mongod)?

Tags: node.js

i am following the REST convention making a blog site , during edit and update route i used method overriding for put request , but when i submit the updated blog, it shows this error:

{ CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value " 5eb4e6190ce97a09f7484ed5" at path "_id" for model "Blog"
 message:
   'Cast to ObjectId failed for value " 5eb4e6190ce97a09f7484ed5" at path "_id" for model "Blog"',
  name: 'CastError',
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '" 5eb4e6190ce97a09f7484ed5"',
  kind: undefined,
  value: ' 5eb4e6190ce97a09f7484ed5',
  path: '_id',
  reason:
   Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

code for update route:-

```
app.put("/blogs/:id", function(req,res){
    var ID = {_id: req.params.id};
    Blog.updateOne(ID, req.body.blog, function(err , updatedBlog){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/blogs");
        } else{
            res.redirect("/blogs/"+req.params.id);
        }
    });
});
```

and this is where the form submits(used method-overriding for put request):-

```
<form class="ui form" action="/blogs/ <%= blog._id %>?_method=PUT " method="POST">
```

kindly help me fix this issue.

Comment: Is the problem that you have a space in the `action` attribute of your `<form>` element just before `<%= blog._id %>`?  What happens if you get rid of this space?

Comment: yes that was the issue ,it works fine now thanks@LukeWoodward but how a beginner is supposed to know that even space matters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, the fix was to remove the errant space in the `action` attribute of the `<form>`, i.e. to replace

```html
<form class="ui form" action="/blogs/ <%= blog._id %>?_method=PUT " method="POST">
```

with

```html
<form class="ui form" action="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>?_method=PUT " method="POST">
```

How to figure this out?  Take a closer look at the error message.  It's complaining about the value

```
' 5eb4e6190ce97a09f7484ed5'
```

not being

> a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters.

And indeed it is neither of these things: it's a space followed by 24 hex characters.  If we can get rid of the space, we will then have a string of 24 hex characters so we should avoid this error.  The error message also mentions that the problem is with a property named `_id`, the value of which comes from the `:id` part of the URL pattern `/blogs/:id`.  Taking a look at the `action` in your `form` element, there is indeed a space after `/blogs/`, which is in the right place to add the extra space to your `id`.  Therefore, it looks likely that this is the problem, so remove this space and try again.

Are you supposed to know that spaces like this matter?  Possibly not, but in this case the error message provides you the hint that it in this case it does.